# Code returns error in Compiler

Tags: c

My compiler throws the following errors:

```
    In function 'main':
    19  2   [Error] incompatible type for argument 1 of 'CommonLocality'
    15  6   [Note] expected 'struct InternetAddress *' but argument is of type 'InternetAddress'
    In function 'ExactInternetAddress':
    34  2   [Error] incompatible types when returning type 'struct InternetAddress *' but 'InternetAddress' was expected
```

I have no idea what to do now and I have a feeling this is something simple. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `InternetAddress` and `InternetAddress *` are not the same type.

Comment: "`expected 'struct InternetAddress *' but argument is of type 'InternetAddress'`" - isn't this clear enough? `ExactInternetAddress` returns a struct (copied by value), and `CommonLocality` expects a **pointer** to a struct. Changing the return type of `ExactInternetAddress` should do the job, most likely. Also, you never `free` the `malloc`ed array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this lines.

```
14: InternetAddress *ExactInternetAddress(char *filename);
18: char filename [] = "internetaddress.txt";
24: InternetAddress *ExactInternetAddress(char *filename) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:
`InternetAddress ExactInternetAddress(char *filename)`
This function returns an Object of type `InternetAddress`.
However the function `void CommonLocality(InternetAddress *var)`
input parameter is a pointer of type `InternetAddress`.

You should rework your code to match the types.

Answer (score 0):

For this error:

> 2   [Error] incompatible type for argument 1 of 'CommonLocality':

Here the problem is that the function "CommonLocality" expects argument to be pointer to struct `InternetAddress`, but what you are passing is just a struct to `InternetAddress`.

Please check this as I have made a small correction in your code:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <string.h>
  4
  5 typedef struct {
  6         int xx;
  7         int yy;
  8         int zz;
  9         int mm;
 10         char nickname[20];
 11 } InternetAddress;
 12
 13 int size;
 14 InternetAddress *ExactInternetAddress(char *filename);
 15 void CommonLocality(InternetAddress* var);
 16
 17 int main() {
 18     char *filename = "internetaddress.txt";
 19     //InternetAddress addr = ExactInternetAddress(filename);
 20     CommonLocality(ExactInternetAddress(filename));
 21     //CommonLocality(&addr);
 22
 23     return 0;
 24 }
 25
 26 InternetAddress *ExactInternetAddress(char *filename) {
 27     FILE *fptr;
 28     fptr = fopen(filename , "r" );
 29     int i;
 30     fscanf(fptr,"%d",&size);
 31     InternetAddress *arr = malloc(size*sizeof(InternetAddress));
 32     for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 33         fscanf(fptr,"%d.%d.%d.%d %s", &arr[i].xx, &arr[i].yy, &arr[i].zz, &arr[i].mm, arr[i].nickname);
 34         fscanf(fptr,"%d.%d.%d.%d %s", &arr[i].xx, &arr[i].yy, &arr[i].zz, &arr[i].mm, arr[i].nickname);
 35     }
 36     fclose(fptr);
 37     return arr;
 38 }
 39
 40 void CommonLocality(InternetAddress *var) {
 41     int i, j;
 42     for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 43         for(j = i + 1; j < (size - 1); j++) {
 44             if(var[i].xx == var[j].xx && var[i].yy == var[j].yy) {
 45                 printf("Machines %s and %s are on the same local network.", var[i].nickname, var[j].nickname);
 46             }
 47         }
 48     }
 49 }
```